# pjax not working on website

Tags: javascript, html, pjax

So I've been trying to make pjax work on my website but with little luck.
What I want to do is very basic and simple. I just want to create two links on my home page which both load a common page. But one link would load it using pjax, thus only change the contents of the div, and the other one would not use pjax and thus load the whole page.

This is the code of my main page (main.html) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Pjax Tutorial</title>
        <script src='node_modules/pjax/pjax.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src='main.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1>Welcome to Pjax tutorial</h1>
        <a id="first-link" class="js-Pjax" href="first.html">First link</a>
        <a id="second-link" href="first.html">Second link</a>   

                <div id="first-div">Index page!</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and this is the code of the common page both links refer to (first.html) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Pjax Tutorial</title>
        <script src='node_modules/pjax/pjax.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src='main.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1>Welcome to Pjax tutorial</h1>
        <a id="first-link" class="js-Pjax" href="first.html">First link</a>
        <a id="second-link" href="first.html">Second link</a>   

                <div id="first-div">This is the first page! If you came here from the first link, then you can notice that the page didn't load but only the URL and the contents of this div were changed. Yay! If you came here from the second link then you can notice that the page actually loaded and each and everything was re-executed(JS) and re-applied(CSS) again. Boo!</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and this is the javascript that I'm using (main.js) -

```
var a = new Pjax({
    elements: "a.js-Pjax",
    selectors: ["#first-div"]
});
```

What it should do is if I click on first link, it should just replace the content of div and change the URL of the page whereas if I click on second link, it should load the page instead of just changing the div and URL.

I've written identical code in play framework (MVC) and it's working perfectly but according to me I should not be needing an MVC to run only this much of code.

I have got the Pjax from here: https://github.com/MoOx/pjax . Installed it through npm.

I've run `Pjax.isSupported()` command and that returned true.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well two things to notice here, combination of which solved my problem.

First, The call to main.js or the javascript file I have written has to be done at the end of the body tag. Something like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Pjax Tutorial</title>
        <script src='node_modules/pjax/pjax.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1>Welcome to Pjax tutorial</h1>
        <a id="first-link" class="js-Pjax" href="first.html">First link</a>
        <a id="second-link" href="first.html">Second link</a>   

                <div id="first-div">Index page!</div>
       <script src='main.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

And second, I do need a server running to make pjax work. It's working with both play framework and npm. Doesn't work without a server.

Hope this helps somebody.